# How to sort price and date by Vue in Laravel

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Trying to sort by *price* and by *date*. the code is below. I didn't use the controller for that. is it possible to make it here?

it's "kind" of working. the problem is, when I select price it's not sorting. but when I select date it's sorting but not date price???? after that when I select price one more time then it's sort the date????? AND date is sorting by asc, how can I change it to desc :) I update the code could you please check it? Thank you for helping me out.

### Code Updated 2:

```js
data() {
        return {
            estates: [],
            keyword: '',
            regions:[],
            rooms:[],
            sortType:''

        }
    },
    created(){
        axios.get('/ajax').then((response) => {
            this.estates = response.data;
        });
    },
    computed: {
        one: function () {
        let filteredStates = this.estates.filter((estate) => {
            return (this.keyword.length === 0 || estate.includes(this.keyword)) &&
            (this.rooms.length === 0 || this.rooms.includes(estate.rooms)) &&
            (this.regions.length === 0 || this.regions.includes(estate.region))});

            if(this.sortType == 'price') {
                    this.estates = this.estates.sort((prev, curr) => prev.price - curr.price);
            }
            if(this.sortType == 'created_at') {
                this.estates = this.estates.sort((prev, curr) => Date.parse(prev.created_at) - Date.parse(curr.created_at));
            }

            return filteredStates;
        }
    }
    }
```

```html
<select v-model="sortType" v-on:change="one">
        <option value="">Sort Type</option>
        <option value="price">price</option>
        <option value="created_at">Date</option>
</select>
```

Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to accomplish that would be to store the result of the first sorting in a variable `filteredStates`, and then using the same variable to filter again according to the sort by date.

Code example:

```
computed: {
    one: function () {
        let filteredStates = this.estates.filter((estate) => {
            return (this.keyword.length === 0 || estate.includes(this.keyword)) &&
            (this.rooms.length === 0 || this.rooms.includes(estate.rooms)) &&
            (this.regions.length === 0 || this.regions.includes(estate.region))});


            if (this.sortBy == 'created_at') {
                filteredStates = filteredStates.sort((prev, curr) => Date.parse(prev.created_at) - Date.parse(curr.created_at));
            }

            return filteredStates;
    }
}
```

I'm sure there is a faster way to achieve the same result, but this way is easier to understand what is going on in the code.

Let me know if that works ; )

**UPDATE:**

The problem is that you are using `this.estates` instead of the variable `filteredStates` that has the filtered results stored on it. You have to keep using `filteredStates` in all subsequent filters. Please see example:

```
computed: {
    one: function () {
        let filteredStates = this.estates.filter((estate) => {
            return (this.keyword.length === 0 || estate.includes(this.keyword)) &&
            (this.rooms.length === 0 || this.rooms.includes(estate.rooms)) &&
            (this.regions.length === 0 || this.regions.includes(estate.region))});


            if(this.sortType == 'price') {
                filteredStates = filteredStates.sort((prev, curr) => prev.price - curr.price);
            }
            if(this.sortType == 'created_at') {
                filteredStates = filteredStates.sort((prev, curr) => Date.parse(prev.created_at) - Date.parse(curr.created_at));
            }

            return filteredStates;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer. now it's "kind" of working. the problem is, when I select price it's not sorting. but when I select date it's sorting but not date price???? after that when I select price one more time then it's sort the date????? AND date is sorting by asc, how can I change it to desc :) I update the code could you please check it? Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: Look the code now, I have just updated, you have to continue using the filteredStates variable in all filters.

Comment: wow, it's nearly perfect... Thank you so much. one thing. date is not desc it's asc how to change it to desc?

Comment: change position of curr and prev !

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sort` function on array.

Like:

```
const filtered = [
  {price: 20, date: '12-12-2020'},
  {price: 15, date: '23-12-2019'},
  {price: 23, date: '12-12-2028'},
].sort((prev, curr) => prev.price - curr.price);

console.log(filtered)
```

You can pass you array on my array and return the filtered array.

`prev` is previous object and `curr` is current object.

What is `sort`?

Its a function that provide callback function for sorting the array.

I have sorted is with the price you can try `price` and `date`

For you code:

```
    <select v-model="sortType" v-on:change="sortItem()">
        <option value="">Sort Type</option>
        <option value="price">Price</option>
        <option value="created_at">Date</option>
    </select>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="item of estates">Price: {{item.price}}, Date: {{item.created_at}}</li>
    </ul>
```

**Script:**

```
        data: () => {
            return {
                sortType: '',
                estates: []
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.estates = [{
                    price: 20,
                    created_at: '2019-01-28 09:31:42'
                },
                {
                    price: 15,
                    created_at: '2019-01-28 09:31:42'
                },
                {
                    price: 23,
                    created_at: '2019-01-28 09:30:42'
                },
            ];
        },
        methods: {
            sortItem() {
                if (this.sortType == 'price') {
                    this.estates = this.estates.sort((prev, curr) => prev.price - curr.price);
                }
                if (this.sortType == 'created_at') {
                    this.estates = this.estates.sort((prev, curr) => Date.parse(prev.created_at) - Date.parse(curr.created_at));
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: thank you for reply. I can't explain well I think, i am having trouble to implementing on my function "this" sorting, could you edit your asnwer while using my code? that would be a better example and explanation for me how to use sort...

Comment: Ofcourse...
Can you send me that list of data of 5 records?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/FTFsc0F here. you can see there is "price" and "created_at" columns. Thank you!

Comment: thank you for, edit it working. kind of... but it's another method. the problem how can I insert this inside compute: one function... with other filters... and make it two different select boxes.

Comment: I update the code in the question. could check it out?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using sort in Vue computed:
https://jsfiddle.net/jxuLdhz3/

```
sortedItems() {
  if (this.sortBy === 'by-date') {
    return this.items.sort((prev, curr) => {
        return new Date(prev.date) - new Date(curr.date);
    });
  }
  if (this.sortBy === 'by-price') {
    return this.items.sort((prev, curr) => {
        return prev.price - curr.price;
    });
  }
  return this.items;
},
```

Sort reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

---

UPD-01:
If you need to sort by several fields i recommend you to use a lodash.js

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#orderBy

http://jsfiddle.net/cuq0vmy5

`_.orderBy(this.items, ['price', 'date'], ['asc', 'asc']);`

Comment: you make a different function, how can I insert it to my "one" function and use it with other sort options...? And also I am trying to make two selectbox... Thank you.

Comment: how it should be sorted first - by date or by price (if user selects both of them)?

Comment: that's why I try to add two select boxes. and try add it in my "one" function, and use " || "

Comment: one (price or date) should have a priority. How do you want to sort the list? By date and after by price (if items have the same date). Or by price and after by date?

Comment: oh, I want to sort first price and after date

Comment: i recommend you to use lodash.js library for such things :)
https://jsfiddle.net/cuq0vmy5/ https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#orderBy

Comment: thank you for edit. but still it's not in the one function. :))) do you see the one function in the question right? computed: one i want it inside that function. So i can use it with the other filters....

Comment: put orderBy in your `one` function. It should work. Name of function (`one` or `sortedItems`) not matters :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187555/discussion-between-barbie-and-gleam).

Comment: okay how can I put it in my "one" function. I asking it from start in the in the question...

Comment: I need a complete example to help. Couldn't help without a repro. Sorry.

Comment: okay, I update the question. check it out please. I need exactly someting like that... Thank you :)